# Could a translation error lead to squares to not be considered as rectangles?

Tags: translation, word-choice, meaning, difference

I'm reading a certain set of kindergarten/lower primary maths textbooks that is written by North American authors for an Asian company.

Whenever students are asked to identify the number of rectangles in a given picture, the answer booklet gives the number of oblongs instead of the number of rectangles.

While the topic may be too advanced for kindergarten students, the maths textbooks indeed explicitly say at the bottom of the first page of a textbook at the very first level to tell students that squares are special types of rectangles, where levels 1-4 are for kindergarten students.

Additionally, the accompany guide for teachers devotes a whole page of discussion as to how to teach that squares are special types of rectangles. There's even a paragraph about teaching to kindergarten students. The authors/some of the co-authors of the teacher guides are also authors/co-authors of the textbooks. They have also said that if students are taught that squares are not rectangles, then they will have misconceptions later.

Perhaps, the ones who wrote the answer booklets were not fluent in English while the ones who wrote the textbooks were.

For example

> [picture with 4 circles, 2 triangles, 3 square rectangles, 2 oblong rectangles for a total of 5 rectangles]
>
> Circle ___
>
> Triangle ___
>
> Square ___
>
> Rectangle ___

The answer key would give only the numbers:

> 4
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 2

So, the last line is wrong since it should be 5.

Could this happen in Korean? Or a Korean dialect? I mean, is there something specific about the translations of any of the following words 'rectangle, square, oblong, quadrilateral, quadrangle, parallelogram, trapezoid/trapezium, rhombus' that would cause such confusion? I guess the translator/s thought that when English speakers say 'rectangle', it means 'oblong in their language/dialect, but I don't see that as specifically a problem for this particular language.

By the way, are squares considered rectangles in Korea?

Related:

[Are kindergartners supposed to be steered from squares being rectangles?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/13831/)

[In what curricula are “rectangles” defined so as to exclude squares?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/13700/in-what-curricula-are-rectangles-defined-so-as-to-exclude-squares)

[Why do we have circles for ellipses, squares for rectangles but nothing for triangles?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2249741/why-do-we-have-circles-for-ellipses-squares-for-rectangles-but-nothing-for-tria)

[What are/should kids (be) taught about the colour of the sun?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/394471)

Comment: squares are  a special case of rectangles I suppose

Comment: @user17915 Do you have a Korean Education Department of the Government document to support your claim please?

Comment: https://math.okstate.edu/geoset/Projects/Ideas/SquareRect.htm

Comment: @user17915 Oklahoma is in the u.s. this is Korean s.e....

Comment: As you say these books were written by American authors, I'm a bit unclear where translation to or from Korean took place here?

Comment: @topomorto Thanks! I don't want to say the actual language out of fear of identification. But if we suppose the company for example is Korean, is there some aspect of the Korean language that would make it plausible that the mistake/s would be due to a translation error rather than a geometric misconception?

Comment: @topomorto Oh right as for where exactly could the translation error be: I'm not sure myself. It could be 1. textbooks english originally then read by non-fluent english 2. textbooks non-english originally then translated then read by non-fluent english 3. non-english textbooks read (either by fluent or non-fluent of that language) though that's not the one i came across 4. in any case, it could be that the ones who wrote the answer booklets were not the ones who wrote the textbooks 5. any valid combination of the previous

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Could this happen in Korean? Or a Korean dialect?

Nah, not at all. This is just an obvious geometric concept. Korean language does not have a single word for a `non-square rectangle`, which might have caused such a translation problem if it existed; so **it has nothing to do with Korean language.**

The Korean terms have the same definitions with the English ones:

- A `quadrangle` is a `사각형 (四角形)`, where `四` means `four`, `角` means `angle`, and `形` means `shape`: *a four-sided plane figure, especially a square or rectangle*.
- A `rectangle` is a `직사각형 (直四角形)`, where `直` means `perpendicular`, and `四角形` means a `quadrangle`: *a plane figure with four straight sides and four right angles, **especially** one with unequal adjacent sides*.
- A `square` is a `정사각형 (正四角形)`, where `正` means `right` and `neat`, and `四角形` means a `quadrangle`: *a plane figure with four equal straight sides and four right angles*.
- `사각형` (`quadrangle`) ⊃ `직사각형` (`rectangle`) ⊃ `정사각형` (`square`).

---

## It's just that they *misused* the term `rectangle`.

The thing is that they just used `rectangle` to mean *one with unequal adjacent sides*, which might not be a good practice, and it has nothing to do with linguistic inter-language terminology confusion.

Comment: Thanks K._! If I understand right, your opinion is that Korean doesn't have a word for non-square rectangle and hence this is probably not a Korean thing? So, to generalise, if we were dealing with a language without a word for non-square rectangle then the issue is probably not with the language? (I'm not as confident as you, so I include the word 'probably'! Haha)

Comment: @BCLC Maybe. Since they used `rectangle` to mean oblong rectangles, to assume this issue to be a wrong translation, there should be a word for an oblong rectangle in the original language, which might be the cause for the wrong translation.

Comment: @BCLC Please feel free to _accept_ my answer if you find it's helpful. :)

Comment: waiting for bounty to end. During bounty period I hope to attract to attention to my question . Hopefully some of that attention will also be toward your answer. Thus, your answer will have further support, have review, be proven outright wrong or any combination of the aforementioned.

Answer (score 0):

quadrangle=quadrilateral=tetragon=사각형

rectangle =직사각형 (quadrangle with four right angles)

regular tetragon=square=정사각형 (which is included in rectangle)

oblong rectangle (In the context, this is a rectangle which is not a square. But in Korea, I never heard a specific word. We do not use frequently. If we are in the situation, then we say 정사각형이 아닌 직사각형)

parallelogram =평행사변형 (quadrangle such that any side is parallel to the side in facing position)

trapezoid/trapezium=사다리꼴 (quadrangle such that there is a side parallel to the side in facing position)

rhombus=마름모 (quadrangle with four sides of equal lengths)

Comment: HK Lee, thanks. So, what exactly is your answer? Could this probably be a Korean-language/Korean-culture thing? Or probably not?

Comment: In general, 4, 2, 3, 5. But if your book answers 4,2,3,2, then it may be correct. I believe that the book distinguish rectangle and square.

Comment: HK Lee, I mean, what is your answer to whether or not this may be a Korean-language/Korean-culture issue instead of a regular common geometric misconception issue? Also, edited question

Comment: Frankly, I do not catch your question exactly : (1)
This may be Korean language issue ? Here what is this ? (2) To the
last question in OP, I answer that the square is an example of
rectangle in Korea (Yes, it is considered rectangle).

Comment: For (1), you mean whether or not Korea children confuse square and
rectangle frequently ?

Comment: HK Lee, I'm not asking about Korean children or adults. I'm asking about the Korean language. The thing is the answer booklets do not treat squares as rectangles even if the teacher guides and level 1 of the textbooks says squares are rectangle. My question: is it possible that the reason why this is so is due to some translation error related to the Korean language?

Comment: My answer is "it is not a translation error" to your question. As far as I know, terminology in math can not be extended or diminished, since it cause a confusion. So I believe that it is not translation error. I guess that it is a printing error. The book may miss the word oblong in front of rectangle.

Comment: it's not a printing error. This happened in all the answer booklets.